# Qual o tamanho da memória de acordo com o tamanho do endereço?

Tags: memória, arquitetura-computadores

Estou tendo algumas dificuldades pra responder duas perguntas baseadas nas seguintes informações:

- Possui suporte em hardware à memória virtual;
- Trabalha com páginas de 1KB;
- Trabalha com endereços virtuais de 24 bits;
- Trabalha com endereços físicos de 16 bits;
- Possui somente 1 tabela de páginas para mapeamento de todo o espaço de endereçamento
  virtual;

Qual a quantidade máxima de memória física que pode ser instalada?

Qual a quantidade máxima de memória virtual que pode ser acessada?

Comment: Acho que essa pergunta é fora do escopo.

Comment: Pensei que como o endereço fisico tem 16 bits, a quantidade de endereços que eu posso alocar é de 2^16, ou seja 65MB, mas não sei se isso está correto.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

É pura matemática.

> Qual a quantidade máxima de memória física que pode ser instalada?

2 (a quantidade de valores que um 1 pode ter) elevado a 16 (a quantidade de bits disponíveis) faz dar 65536, ou 64KB.

> Qual a quantidade máxima de memória virtual que pode ser acessada?

Aqui é 2 elevado a 24 que dá 16MB.

As demais informações são irrelevantes para essas perguntas.

Comment: Obrigado cara!! Tava com esse pensamento ai mas não sabia se estava correto... Muito obrigado :)

Comment: Quando é assim, coloque o que estava achando que é.